# Converting a Promise to a JSON object using fetch in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, api, promise, wikipedia-api

The JavaScript code below attempts to pull data from the Wikipedia API using fetch; however, it encounters the following error:

**The code:**

```
const endpoint = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=Hello&format=json&origin=*&callback=?";
fetch(endpoint).then(blob => console.log(blob.json()));
```

**The error:**

index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0

**This is what the API returns:**

```
/**/(["Hello",["Hello","Hello, Dolly! (musical)","Hello Kitty","Hello (Adele song)","Hello Venus","Helloween","Hello Counselor","Hello, Goodbye","Hello! Project","Hello, Dolly! (film)"],["Hello is a salutation or greeting in the English language. It is first attested in writing from 1826.","Hello, Dolly! is a 1964 musical with lyrics and music by Jerry Herman and a book by Michael Stewart, based on Thornton Wilder's 1938 farce The Merchant of Yonkers, which Wilder revised and retitled The Matchmaker in 1955. The musical follows the story of Dolly Levi (a strong-willed matchmaker), as she travels to Yonkers, New York, to find a match for the miserly \"well-known unmarried half-a-millionaire\" Horace Vandergelder.","Hello Kitty (Japanese: \u30cf\u30ed\u30fc\u30fb\u30ad\u30c6\u30a3, Hepburn: Har\u014d Kiti) (full name: Kitty White (\u30ad\u30c6\u30a3\u30fb\u30db\u30ef\u30a4\u30c8, Kiti Howaito)) is a fictional character produced by the Japanese company Sanrio, created by Yuko Shimizu and currently designed by Yuko Yamaguchi.","\"Hello\" is a song by English singer Adele, released on 23 October 2015 by XL Recordings as the lead single from her third studio album, 25 (2015).","Hello Venus (Hangul: \ud5ec\ub85c\ube44\ub108\uc2a4; often stylized as HELLOVENUS) is a South Korean girl group formed by Tricell Media, a joint venture between Pledis Entertainment and Fantagio, in 2012. The group originally consisted of six members: Alice, Nara, Lime, Yooara, Yoonjo, and Yooyoung.","Helloween is a German power metal band founded in 1984 in Hamburg, Northern Germany by members of bands Iron Fist and Gentry.","Hello Counselor (Hangul: \uc548\ub155\ud558\uc138\uc694; RR: Annyeonghaseyo; lit. Hello) is a South Korean reality show that debuted in November 2010. It is hosted by Shin Dong-yup, Lee Young-ja, and Cultwo (Jung Chan-woo, Kim Tae-gyun).","\"Hello, Goodbye\" is a song by the English rock band the Beatles, written by Paul McCartney and credited to Lennon\u2013McCartney.","Hello! Project (\u30cf\u30ed\u30fc!\u30d7\u30ed\u30b8\u30a7\u30af\u30c8, Har\u014d! Purojekuto) is a Japanese idol project, the umbrella name for a collective of female singers who are under contract with the Up-Front Group and whose recordings are produced by Tsunku.","Hello, Dolly! is a 1969 American romantic comedy musical film based on the Broadway production of the same name."],["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello,_Dolly!_(musical)","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_Kitty","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_(Adele_song)","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_Venus","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helloween","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_Counselor","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello,_Goodbye","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello!_Project","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello,_Dolly!_(film)"]])
```

As you can tell, the error is the result of the API returning a string beginning with /**/, which the .json() method cannot interpret (according to the error message).

**My question:**

Given that I have already specified in my API call to return my data in JSON format (format=json), how should I deal with the fact that .json() cannot convert the returned string into a JSON object?

Should I just call the .text() method on blob, save the result in a string, remove the /**/ symbol and then use JSON.parse() to convert the string into a JSON object?

Also, is there a reason why Wikipedia appends /**/ before the returned string?

**P.S. I am looking for solutions in pure JavaScript**

Comment: remove `&callback=?`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Wikipedia's API to fetch results from search query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985111/using-wikipedias-api-to-fetch-results-from-search-query)

Comment: Thanks Jaromanda X. Your solution worked. Can you explain why?

Comment: Search for `JSONP`

Comment: The idea here is that you set the `callback` parameter to something meaningful like `myMethod`. The response won't be JSON, it will be Javascript code that calls `myMethod` with the data as parameter. (You might have seen the `?` in jQuery calls but jQuery actually replaces it with a random-generated name before making the call.)